# ASP.NET: Unable to retrieve values for controls located in a panel after postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback

I've placed some controls in a panels. When the page postback, I'm trying to retrieve the posted values, but only the older value seems to be there.

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
  Dim _txtFName As TextBox = FindControl("editNamePanel").FindControl("txtFName")
  Dim _txtMName As TextBox = FindControl("editNamePanel").FindControl("txtMName")
  Dim _txtLName As TextBox = FindControl("editNamePanel").FindControl("txtLName")
End Sub
```

Even when I hover over the e EventArgs is null. Am I missing something?

## EDIT

I'm getting new values when I put the above code in the page load event handler

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Me.Load
   If Page.IsPostBack Then
      'The above code here ...
   End If
End Sub
```

Thank for helping

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx

```
<asp:Panel ID="editNamePanel" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

In your code behind

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim _txtFName As TextBox = txtFName
    Dim _txtMName As TextBox = txtMName
    Dim _txtLName As TextBox = txtLName
End Sub
```

Comment: That didn't change the outcome. I still get the older values.